# Django manage.py commands generate error in Cronjob

Tags: python, django, cron

Whenever I'm running a manage.py command (e.g. migrate, runserver) everything is fine.
I'm using the following Cronjob command:

```
* * * * * python3 /home/ec2-user/Project/manage.py migrate
```

However, whenever I'm scheduling a manage.py command in Crontab, the following error comes up:

```
File "/home/ec2-user/project/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ec2-user/project/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 207, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 204, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 73, in <module>
    check_sqlite_version()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 69, in check_sqlite_version
    'SQLite 3.9.0 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite_version
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.9.0 or later is required (found 3.7.17).
```

I have already updated SQLite to 3.3.38, which the Python shell confirms:

```
Python 3.7.10 (default, Jun  3 2021, 00:02:01) 
[GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-13)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.38.5'
```

Comment: Is it a possibility that the cronjob and when u run manually use different enviroments? Maybe just try to let cronjob display the packages installed (python3 -m pip freeze). This way you are sure which version of sqlite3 is used by the cronjob

Comment: Hi Leeuwtje, thanks for reaching out! I let Cronjob run this command, but SQLite3 is not displayed in the list.

Comment: That probably means that the python used by cronjob is different that if you run it manually. you could always try `pip install --upgrade pysqlite`. But if I may ask, why do you want to add django command to cronjob? For development it is easy to migrate after pulling new changes from git or when you make migrations on you own. And for production there should be a workflow (automatic or manually) that takes the code down, runs migrations/collect_static/other management-commands and than restarts the codebase with the new version. And please, dont use runserver on production. It is unsecure

Comment: Hi Leeuwtje, I don't intend using 'migrate' in Cronjob. I've written some custom commands, which are generating the same error. I figured that the SQLite3 error was not generated by my custom commands, but just a general Cronjob/Django issue.

Comment: The thing is, issuing manage.py commands through sudo gives me the same error. I'm certain the env is the problem, but I can't seem to find any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find the origin of the issue. However, downgrading my Django version to 2.0 does resolve the issue, because this version of Django doesn't verify the SQLite3 version.